# Does $P(A’\cap B)= P(B)-P(B\cap A)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let A and B be sets. I want to know if $P(A-B)= P(A)-P(B)$. More specific, I need to calculate $P(A’\cap B)$ using that $A’\cap B= B-B\cap A $, but I don’t know if I can simply do $P(A’\cap B)= P(B)-P(B\cap A)$

Comment: Yes, it's correct. If $A\subset B$, then the first identity you wrote is true.

Comment: Only when $A \subset B$ or more generally, when $A \setminus B$ has zero probability.

Comment: In case the other statements were not clear enough, $\Pr(A\setminus B)$ is not equal to $\Pr(A)-\Pr(B)$ in general but will be equal under certain circumstances.  $\Pr(A\cap B')=\Pr(A)-\Pr(A\cap B)$ is indeed true and follows from the law of total probability.  From this, we learn that the proposed identity in the first line will be true, that is $\Pr(A\setminus B)=\Pr(A)-\Pr(B)$ will be true, specifically when $\Pr(B)=\Pr(A\cap B)$